# Image is not drawn at the correct spot

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, image-processing, gdi+

```
Bitmap image = ReadBitmap("image.png");
Bitmap imageCopy = new Bitmap(image);
Bitmap canvas = new Bitmap(imageCopy.Width+100, imageCopy.Height);

// From this bitmap, the graphics can be obtained, because it has the right PixelFormat
using(Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(canvas))
{
    // Draw the original bitmap onto the graphics of the new bitmap
    g.DrawImage(image, 0, 0);
}

// Use tempBitmap as you would have used originalBmp
InputPictureBox.Image = image;
OutputPictureBox.Image = canvas;
```

[image: Sample Image]

I haven't understood the output of this c# code.

The original image is not placed at the correct position. It should have been at `(0, 0)`.
Also, I need a black background.

So, what is going on and how to correct this?

Comment: This code copies the source image into a new Image container. The destination container size is increased in its X dimension of 100 pixels. The source Image is then copied into the new container. Since only the origin point is specified, the source Image is distorted to fit it's container. The source Image is untouched. Both Images are passed to PictureBoxes. How the Images are presented on the Controls, it depends on the Controls SizeMode (zoom, stretch, autosize...). *I needed a black background*: on the Image copy? If so, you have filled the canvas completely when drawing into it).

Comment: Also, none of the Images is Disposed and the source Image will be locked by GDI+ (you can't touch the underlying file until the Image (and its stream) is `Disposed()`. You should explain what was the intended result. Possibly, create a larger Canvas, as a black frame for the Image, in its left and right sides?

Comment: @Jimi *Since only the origin point is specified, the source Image is distorted to fit it's container.* No. The image is drawn with its **original** size. The distortion whould have been made if he had specified width and height *g.DrawImage(image, 0, 0, canvas.Width, canvas.Height)*

Comment: You have *zoom* in your pic box. Change it to *normal*.

Comment: @γηράσκω δ' αεί πολλά διδασκόμε  Yes, maybe *distorted* wasn't the word of choice. Enlarged (kind of a distortion). But should also be cropped (Y dimension).

Comment: You should not draw the image by yourself, just set it as the source to the second PictureBox and set the [zoom mode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.forms.picturebox.sizemode(v=vs.110).aspx) correctly.

Comment: @Jimi As i said he only provided the position in his draw call *g.DrawImage(image, 0, 0);*, so *image* will be drawn with its own size. Canvas size doesn't matter except if the original image is larger, then it will be cropped. Do an experiment. Make canvas double the size. The original image  will be drawn **exactly** as is at (0,0) provided pic box is set to normal.

Comment: You place the image in the canvas which is the same size as the image.  You need to position the canvas by setting top and left properties.

Comment: @γηράσκω δ' αεί πολλά διδασκόμε  Did you check the DPI resolution of the source and the copy? `new Bitmap()` does not respect the original resolution. You have to hope that the original DPI is equal to 96 (or the screen resolution). Or set it manually with `Bitmap.SetResolution()`. Otherwise, you'll see something like in the second image, which has probably a DPI of 96. He might have a HI-DPI screen (120/144 DPI or scaled).

Comment: @γηράσκω δ' αεί πολλά διδασκόμε  I wrote down some notes about what I previously commented about. Maybe, let me know your opinion on this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are loading an Image, then a copy of this source is created using:
`Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap();`

When you create a copy of an Image this way, you sacrifice/alter some details:
**[Dpi Resolution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.setresolution)**: if not otherwise specified, the resolution is set to the UI resolution. 96 Dpi, as a standard; it might be different with different screen resolutions and scaling. The System in use also affects this value (Windows 7 and Windows 10 will probably/possibly provide different values)
**[PixelFormat](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.pixelformat)**: If not directly copied from the Image source or explicitly specified, the `PixelFormat` is set to `PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb`.

From what you were saying, you probably wanted something like this:

```
var imageSource = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(@"[SomeImageOfLena]"))), true, false)
var imageCopy = new Bitmap(imageSource.Width + 100, imageSource.Height, imageSource.PixelFormat))

imageCopy.SetResolution(imageSource.HorizontalResolution, imageSource.VerticalResolution);
using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(imageCopy)) {
    g.Clear(Color.Black);
    g.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
    g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
    g.DrawImage(imageSource, (imageCopy.Width - imageSource.Width) / 2, 0);

    pictureBox1.Image?.Dispose();
    pictureBox2.Image?.Dispose();
    pictureBox1.Image = imageSource;
    pictureBox2.Image = imageCopy;
}
```

This is the result:
(The upper/lower frame black color is actually the `Picturebox` background color)

[image: Corrected DPI]

When the original Image Dpi Resolution is different from the base Dpi Resolution used when creating an Image copy with `new Bitmap()`, your results may be different from what is expected.

This is what happens with a source Image of 150, 96 and 72 Dpi in the same scenario:

[image: Original DPI]

Also, possibly, don't assign an `Image` object directly loaded from a `FileStream` or - way worse - using `Image.FromFile()` (slow, ignores ICM unless instructed: nobody ever does it)
GDI+ will lock the file, and you will not be able to copy, move or delete it.
With the file, all resources tied to the Images will also be locked.

I suggest using the [Image.FromStream(Stream, Boolean, Boolean)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.fromstream?view=windowsdesktop-7.0#system-drawing-image-fromstream(system-io-stream-system-boolean-system-boolean)) overload, passing a MemoryStream, filled calling `File.ReadAllBytes()`. E.g.,

```
var image = Image.FromStream(new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes([Image Path])), true, false);
```

This instructs to consider embedded ICM information (when present) to preserve the colors and to bypass data validation (this speeds up the process quite a bit)

[Image.Clone()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.clone) can also be used to duplicate an Image, it will preserve the Image `Dpi Resolution` and `PixelFormat`.

Another important detail is the [IDisposable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable) nature of the Image object.
When you create one, you have to [Dispose()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.idisposable.dispose) of it; explicitly, calling the `Dispose` method, or implicitly, enclosing the Image contructor in a [Using statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement).

Answer (score 0):

I am not completely clear on what you are actually needing to do. But anyway, here is a WPF-friendly example of how to draw an image at a specific position inside another image.

Note if all you want to do is display the image in different size and/or put a black border around it, there are much simpler ways to do simply that, without having to create a second image, such as just laying out the image inside a panel that already has the border style you want.

Notice that I am using classes from the System.Windows.Media namespace because that is what WPF uses. These don't mix easily with the older classes from System.Drawing namespace (some of the class names conflict, and Microsoft's .Net framework lacks built-in methods for converting objects between those types), so normally one needs to simply decide whether to use one or the other sets of drawing tools. I assume you have been trying to use System.Drawing. Each has its own pros and cons that would take too long to explain here.

```
// using System.Windows.Media;
// using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
private void DrawTwoImages()
{
    // For InputPictureBox
    var file = new Uri("C:\\image.png");
    var inputImage = new BitmapImage(file);
        // If your image is stored in a Resource Dictionary, instead use:
        //     var inputImage = (BitmapImage) Resources["image.png"];
    InputPicture.Source = inputImage;

    // imageCopy isn't actually needed for this example.
    // But since you had it in yours, here is how it's done, anyway.
    var imageCopy = inputImage.Clone();

    // Parameters for setting up our output picture
    int leftMargin   = 50;
    int topMargin    = 5;
    int rightMargin  = 50;
    int bottomMargin = 5;
    int width  = inputImage.PixelWidth  + leftMargin + rightMargin;
    int height = inputImage.PixelHeight + topMargin  + bottomMargin;
    var backgroundColor = Brushes.Black;
    var borderColor = (Pen) null; 

    // Use a DrawingVisual and DrawingContext for drawing
    DrawingVisual dv = new DrawingVisual();
    using (DrawingContext dc = dv.RenderOpen())
    {
        // Draw the black background
        dc.DrawRectangle(backgroundColor, borderColor, new Rect(0, 0, width, height));

        // Copy input image onto output image at desired position
        dc.DrawImage(inputImage, new Rect(leftMargin, topMargin,
                     inputImage.PixelWidth, inputImage.PixelHeight));
    }

    // For displaying output image
    var rtb = new RenderTargetBitmap( width, height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Pbgra32 );
    rtb.Render(dv);
    OutputPicture.Source = rtb;
}
```