# C#.net image rescaling color issues

Tags: c#, bitmap, scaling

I am trying to rescale an image on the fly with c#.net.  Everything appeared to be working correctly, but upon closer inspection, the colors do not look right.

The code appears to be pretty straight forward and it rescales fine, but why does the original image appear a pinker color than the scaled picture?

```
using (Bitmap origBitmap = new Bitmap("my_picture.jpg"))
{
    using (Bitmap outputImage = new Bitmap(1024, 768, origBitmap.PixelFormat))
    {
        outputImage.SetResolution(origBitmap.HorizontalResolution, origBitmap.VerticalResolution);
        using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(outputImage))
        {
            g.Clear(Color.Black);
            g.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceCopy;
            g.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;

            g.DrawImage(
                origBitmap,
                new Rectangle(0, 0, 1024, 768),
                new Rectangle(0, 0, origBitmap.Width, origBitmap.Height),
                GraphicsUnit.Pixel
            );

            context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
            outputImage.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        }
    }
}
```

Attached you can see the difference in the colors.  Hoping I am missing something simple?

[picture_scaling_issues.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lHtrf.jpg)

Comment: This is not a good way to rescale an Image. Are you scaling up or down? In the meanwhile, see [InterpolationMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.interpolationmode) and [CompositingQuality](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.compositingquality).

Comment: Sample code and some tips [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51453564/image-is-not-drawn-at-the-correct-spot?answertab=active#tab-top).

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is this a bad way to do it?  The reason I am using ImageFormat is because it has a RotateFlip function and I need to be able to flip the image to a different orientation.

Comment: Sorry I should have read your links before asking why it was a bad method.  :)  Ok, I will take a look at those examples this evening and see if it makes a difference.  Thank you for the quick reply!

Comment: `ImageFormat` *may* also have its role. GDI+ is optimized for PNG rendering. It's its default format. The `.Jpg` format (lacking an effective control on its lossy compression) is really not. This doesn't mean that the Image colors are mistreated. But the quality could be disappointing when resampling. Applying a matrix transformation like `RotateFlip` doesn't compromise the output quality.

Comment: @Jimi - I tried the examples on the site and updated my question above to reflect it.  It still renders the exact same as the old way.  I am creating this as a way to scale pictures on a photography website, and they aren't all that happy that the colors don't match their originals.... Anything else you can think of to try to get the colors to match?

Comment: Can you test the output using `PNG` as format? If you *need* to use `JPEG`, you'll have to set the Encoder Quality before sending the Image to the Stream. Test this saving the resulting Image to a File instead of sending it to the Browser (given the destination enviroment, the Quality might be insufficient to preserve the filter applied to the original image).

Comment: Just a detail: you don't need `g.Clear(Color.Black);`. Your image will fill the Bitmap canvas completely. It's useless (here) and it take its time.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like I answered my own question!

```
using (Bitmap origBitmap = (Bitmap) Bitmap.FromFile("my_file.jpg", true))
{ … }
```

The "true" parameter is for "useEmbeddedColorManagement".  Setting that to true fixes the problem...

Comment: This will work when the image actually was saved storing this information. Trying to use the embedded information is a good practice, anyway. If you want, I can post and Encoder Quality setup, so you can control both the resulting DPI of the Image and the overall Image Quality setting (just as a reference, then you can tick your answer).