# Fix background crush C# winforms

Tags: c#, winforms

I work on MDIParent with background image after i move a child from in it the background image crush like this[image]

how can i solve this issue in C# winforms??

Comment: Have you tried to overriding `OnResize` method and implement `Invalidate();` to redrawn the control?

Comment: yes,I tried in MDIParent but i'm not resize form i just move child form in the main form

Comment: Don't ever set `BackgroundImageLayout` to anything else than `Center`. Size your Image beforehand as required.

Comment: I had set it in center

Comment: I made a test. The `MDIClient` Control (the MDI Parent background) is kind of graphics-dumb. It doesn't redraw itself willingly. But, subscribing to it's `Paint` event, you can paint the Image directly in the Graphics context (e.g, with `Graphics.DrawImage`). This will completely solve the problem in relation to the MDI Children movement. Not the MDI Parent resize. You'ld also have to override/subscribe to the MDI Parent `OnResize`/`Resize` and `Invalidate()` the `MDIClient`. This will cause some flickering, though. **Verify the Image DPI resolution**. It's better to explicitly set its size.

Comment: @Jimi Can You Explain more?

Answer (score 0):

The [MDIClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.mdiclient?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.MdiClient);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2) Control is the object used, in Multiple-Document Interface, as the Container for all child Forms.

This Control has a `BackGroundImage` property. You can set an Image object using this property, instead of using the `[MDIParent].BackGroundImage`. This would actually solve the Image tearing problem.
But, you can't set a specific Layout property. See the Docs about the `MDIClient` [BackgroundImageLayout](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.mdiclient.backgroundimagelayout?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Windows_Forms_MdiClient_BackgroundImageLayout):

> This property is not relevant to this class.

You can set this property, but it's ignored: the default `ImageLayout.Tile` is used instead.
A different Layout can be set, assigning the Image object to the `MDIParent` `BackGroundImage` and specifying a `BackGroundImageLayout`. This will change the Layout, but it will also cause the tearing effect you are reporting.

A possible solution is to draw the Image object on the `MDIClient` surface, using it's `Paint()` event as usual.
This will solve the tearing effect. Not the flickering; this can be noticed when you resize the `MDIParent` Form (well, MDI applications are not resized that often, maybe maximized and normalized).
Some flickering can be seen when the background Image is not covered by a child Form.

A small adjustment to the Image specs is required: setting its DPI resolution = to the `MDIParent` reported device context DPI, otherwise the Image size will not match the default size (it's affected by the DPI resolution).

See this post for a description:
[Image is not drawn at the correct spot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51453564/image-is-not-drawn-at-the-correct-spot?answertab=active#tab-top).

An example:
(Here, I assume the background Image is loaded from the Project resources)

```
public partial class MDIParent : Form
{
    private MdiClient mdiBackground = null;
    private Bitmap BackGroundImage = null;

    public MDIParent()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //Specify an existing Resources' Image
        BackGroundImage = new Bitmap(Properties.Resources.[Some Res Image] as Bitmap);
        BackGroundImage.SetResolution(this.DeviceDpi, this.DeviceDpi);
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        mdiBackground = this.Controls.OfType<MdiClient>().First();

        mdiBackground.Paint += (s, evt) => {
            evt.Graphics.DrawImage(BackGroundImage,
                    (mdiBackground.Width - BackGroundImage.Width) / 2.0F,
                    (mdiBackground.Height - BackGroundImage.Height) / 2.0F);
        };
        //Show some child Forms on start-up
    }

    private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.mdiBackground != null) mdiBackground.Invalidate();
    }

    private void MDIParent_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (BackGroundImage != null) BackGroundImage.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Comment: @Abd ul rahaman Shalata  I don't know what that means. As it is, the code draws the Image on the center of the `MdiClient` Control. Is the Image too large? Too small? You just need to use the overload of `Graphics.DrawImage()` that lets specify the Size for the drawing. Do you want it of a specific Size? [Define a Rectangle](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawimage?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Drawing_Graphics_DrawImage_System_Drawing_Image_System_Drawing_Rectangle_) of the size you want. If you need an example for that, let me know.