# Rotated image size increase in mb

Tags: c#, asp.net

Some images are coming rotated in web. so i have rotated the images at the backend with the help of RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone and save the new image. but the image size is increases very much.

Like 200kb becomes 4MB after rotating.

Is there any way to control the size of the rotated image but keeping dimensions same as original image.

**Code**

```
string filename = imagePath.Substring(imagePath.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);

Image image = Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath("~/files/" + filename));

using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image))
{
    if (image.PropertyItems.Any(p => p.Id == 274))
    {
        if (image.PropertyItems.Any(p => p.Value[0] == 6))
        {
            image.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);

            string fileNameWithoutExtnsn = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(imagePath);
            fileNameWithoutExtnsn = fileNameWithoutExtnsn + '1';
            string fileExtnsn = Path.GetExtension(imagePath);
            filename = string.Format("{0}{1}", fileNameWithoutExtnsn, fileExtnsn);
            filePath = string.Format("{0}/{1}/{2}", urlPath, "files", filename);

            try
            {
                image.Save(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/files/"), filename));
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
    }                   
}
```

Comment: have you tried to save it with a imageformat? (`image.Save(Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/files/"), filename), ImageFormat.Png)`)

Comment: i want to save image in same jpeg format only.

Comment: You should be aware that `System.Drawing` is disadviced for server applications. Probably OK for a low traffic site but this won't scale up.

Comment: Some informations on this: [Image is not drawn at the correct spot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51453564/image-is-not-drawn-at-the-correct-spot?answertab=active#tab-top). Are those images only rotated 90° counter-clockwise? I'm asking because you seem to only consider a `PropertyTagOrientation = 6`. You can use the [Image.RawFormat](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.rawformat) to save with the original format  Anyway, see the default format of a Bitmap when no parameters are specified. You should probably adopt an ad-hoc graphics library for this.

Comment: Also, what is the derived Graphics object `using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image))` for? You never use it. Btw, this will always happen when the source image is in JPG format.

Answer (score 0):

RotateFlip convert format to MemoryBmp. So, save image as Jpeg

```
image.Save("filePath", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, I have tried with this also but my image is not rotated after using ImageFormat.Jpeg

Comment: Then you saved the wrong image somehow. Add a section to the question (don't replace the current code).

Comment: @HenkHolterman, I am just rotating the original image and saving it as new image.Can you please tell me how to correct this.

Comment: Not without seeing the new code (including the Jpeg encoder). Do check carefully, if it did totate before then just adding the imageformat should have do the same.