# Image and text gets distorted/blurred on form background

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

I tried this code, it print distorted image and text on black background of a desktop.

I am using a Form with a transparent background. I want to print image on the background.

[image]

```
this.TransparencyKey = BackColor;
Bitmap original = null;
original = new Bitmap(imagePath);
Bitmap newImage = new Bitmap(width, height + rect.Height,  System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
var newGrp = Graphics.FromImage(newImage);
newGrp.Clear(Color.Transparent);
newGrp.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBilinear;
newGrp.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.HighQuality;
newGrp.TextRenderingHint = TextRenderingHint.AntiAlias;
newGrp.CompositingQuality = CompositingQuality.HighQuality;
newGrp.DrawImage(original, 0, rect.Height, width, height);
newGrp.DrawString(text, font, color, textStartPosition, 0);
this.BackgroundImage = (Image)newImage;
```

Original is bitmap from image file and color of text is gray.The form is transparent. The new image is painted as background of form. Depend on background color of desktop(dynamic color), I want to print image on form, But my concerns about text is not clear.
I expect clear image and text on black background.

Comment: What are `width` and `height` here? Why aren't you using `original.Width` and `original.Height`? Did you verify the DPI value of the original Image? See the notes here: [Image is not drawn at the correct spot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51456467/7444103). Remove `newGrp.Clear(Color.Transparent);`. Btw, `newGrp` needs to be disposed of and `newImage` too, at some point. If you then assign the Bitmap to a PictureBox, see that it's `SizeMode` is not set to `StretchImage`.

Comment: But, the title of your question is referring to a PicureBox, while the question itself mentions a Form's background. What is it the destination of this Bitmap?

Comment: I see no distortion. I do see anti-aliasing artifacts. Can you post the `original`?  What is `color`? Is the posted image the resulting bitmap or a screenshot? When you write 'print' you mean 'draw' right? Note that Forms do no support transparency well..

Comment: Original is bitmap from image file and color of text is gray. The new image is painted as background of form. But my concerns about text is not clear.

Comment: You should show the whole procedure, how/when you're drawing that Bitmap. Anyway, since the Form's BackColor is Color.Black, paint the Bitmap after `.Clear(Color.Black);` (or the actual color, if the background of the form it's not exacly Color.Black).

Comment: I have updated question, Please suggest me solution.

Comment: Your transparent Bitmap is probably drawn on a light color. Note that, even if you make your Form transparent, its BackColor is considerend when you draw a semi-transparent Image on it and the Composition is made using the a control's BackColor value to create the blending. If you want your transparent Form to show correncly on a dark background, you have draw the text and the Bitmap setting the Form's BackColor to a dark Color. Try with DarkGray/DimGray first. Conversely, If you draw the Bitmap on a dark color, it will show noticeable artifacts on light backgrounds.