# Position and size of combined images inside a new Bitmap

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics, bitmap, gdi+

I'm trying to combine two semi-transparent PNG images and display the result in a `pictureBox1` which has its `SizeMode` property set to `Zoom`:

```
  pictureBox1.Image = Image.FromFile(imgPath + "/myImg1.png");
```

If I directly display a single image, it is in the center and the existing borders are respected (as shown on the right side of example image below), but if I combines these two images - of the same size:

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    source1 = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(imgPath + "/myImg1.png");
    source2 = (Bitmap)Image.FromFile(imgPath + "/myImg2.png");

    var target = new Bitmap(source1.Width, source1.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
    var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(target);
    graphics.CompositingMode = CompositingMode.SourceOver; 

    graphics.DrawImage(source1, 0, 0);
    graphics.DrawImage(source2, 0, 0);

    pictureBox1.Image = target;
}
```

the actual result shows the two images cropped and not centered (as shown on left side):

[image: Example image]

I'm trying to figure out how control the position and size of the two combined images, so they're drawn as shown in the image on the right.

Comment: [Image is not drawn at the correct spot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51456467/7444103) -- You probably haven't noticed, but your images have a low ressolution (~72dpi), not exactly suited for display. Or printing. Your PC screen has, minimum, a resolution of 96dpi. You then need to generate two new images with the current screen resolution and draw the third, or set the same resolution to the destination image. See the method described in that post.

Comment: Also, note that most phones take photos with that low resolution, which may fit the screen resolution of a phone, not the resolution of a PC screen or a printer. You almost always need this kind of *treatment*. -- `CompositingMode.SourceOver` is the default.

Comment: You want to crop the image.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/winforms/advanced/how-to-crop-and-scale-images?force_isolation=true&view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

Comment: @jdweng The OP doesn't want to crop the resulting image, they want to prevent the Image from being cropped. The reason why that happens has been described. How to solve also.

Comment: @Jimi : The left image is at bottom of picture box while left image the bottom is centered.  To get image centered you need to crop.

Comment: @jdweng That's not what's happening there. The first image is the result of combining the two source images, the second is what the OP wants to achieve. To achieve that, the resolution of the destination image must be the same as the source images. Or, the source images must be rebuilt to match the screen resolution or a resolution specifically defined for a specific use. When this is done, the two images will be copied in the correct position, at the center of the new image -- There's nothing to crop. You need to avoid unwanted cropping. --  Read what's in the Q&A I've linked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The problem**:
The OP is trying to center two images, of the same size in this case, inside a new Bitmap container. The size of the destination Bitmap is set to the size of one of the source images. The new Bitmap should be presented in a PictureBox. The control's `SizeMode` property is set to `SizeMode.Zoom`.

The *unexpected* result is shown in the image on the left, the *expected* result on the right:

[image: Center images no DPI]

**What happens**:
The destination Bitmap is sized as one of the source images, both of the same size.
The two source images are then drawn an `Point(0, 0)` in the new container.
It's expected - since the two semi-transparent images have the same size - that both will be drawn in the original position. The source images instead seem to be enlarged and moved towards the bottom-right corner of the new container.

It doesn't *seem* to be, this is exactly what happens.

The two source Images have a DPI descriptor set to ~72 DPI.
A standard PC screen has a resolution of at least 96 DPI.
When a new Bitmap is created as:

```
var newImage = new Bitmap(source1.Width, source1.Height, PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);
```

the resolution of the new Bitmap is set to the screen resolution, hence at least 96 DPI.

An image loaded using this method:

```
var image = Image.FromFile([Image Path]);
```

is created using the original DPI descriptor and pixel format.

When a 72 DPI image is draw in a 96 DPI container, the different resolution is taken into consideration: the lower resolution image is enlarged.
As a result, the two 72 DPI images, draw inside a 96 DPI container of the same size, are not centered anymore, but it appears they're *moved* down and to the right (thus also clipped).

See also: [Image is not drawn at the correct spot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51456467/7444103)

**How to solve**:
When processing images of - quite possibly - different resolutions, pixel format and size, it's preferable to create a copy of the source images and work with new containers that have the same definition.
So, we can copy the source images to a standard 32Bit ARGB Bitmap (default format, hardware-aligned), setting the resolution to the current screen resolution or specifying a different resolution for specific uses (for printing, for example).
Or a value that a User can specify.

As mentioned, when a new Bitmap container is created as:

```
var bitmap = new Bitmap([width], [height]);
```

the .Net implementation generates a Bitmap with `PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb` and resolution set to what the Application *thinks* is the screen DPI. The value returned by [Control.DeviceDpi](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.devicedpi).
A non DpiAware application will most often *think* it's 96 DPI.

We can nonetheless specify the image resolution using the [Bitmap.SetResolution()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.bitmap.setresolution) method (float values, the DPI is always expressed in floating point values).

This Bitmap constructor:

```
var bitmap = new Bitmap([Stream], true, false))
```

generates a `Format32bppArgb` Bitmap, loads the ICM settings (Color Definition) - if any - and skips the validation of the original Bitmap (often used when a lot of image files are read from disk, it's quite faster. Skipping the ICM mapping is also faster, but can produce wrong colors).

We should also suppose that the two images to center inside the new container, may not have the same exact size (or not the same size at all).
Hence we need a new Bitmap that can contain both images, evaluating the maximum dimension of both.

All considered, the original code can be changed as described in the **`CenterImages()`** method.

The PictureBox Image can be then set as:

```
string image1Path = Path.Combine(imgPath, "myImg1.png");
string image2Path = Path.Combine(imgPath, "myImg2.png");

pictureBox1.Image?.Dispose();
pictureBox1.Image = CenterImages(image1Path, image2Path);
```

to generate a new combined Bitmap using a default 96 DPI resolution. Or as:

```
pictureBox1.Image?.Dispose();
pictureBox1.Image = CenterImages(image1Path, image2Path, 300.0f);
```

to generate a new Bitmap with a resolution of 300 DPI.

---

```
private Bitmap CenterImages(string sourcePath1, string sourcePath2, float dpi = 96.0f)
{
    using (var image1 = new Bitmap(Image.FromStream(
        new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(sourcePath1)), true, false)))
    using (var image2 = new Bitmap(Image.FromStream(
        new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes(sourcePath2)), true, false))) {

        image1.SetResolution(dpi, dpi);
        image2.SetResolution(dpi, dpi);

        var rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, 
            Math.Max(image1.Width, image2.Width), Math.Max(image1.Height, image2.Height));

        var combinedImage = new Bitmap(rect.Width, rect.Height);
        combinedImage.SetResolution(dpi, dpi);

        using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(combinedImage)) {
            graphics.DrawImage(image1, (rect.Width - image1.Width) / 2, (rect.Height - image1.Height) / 2);
            graphics.DrawImage(image2, (rect.Width - image2.Width) / 2, (rect.Height - image2.Height) / 2);
        }
        return combinedImage;
    }
}
```