# Why when cropping part of image from pictureBox2 when displaying the cropped part on pictureBox1 it's not the same cropped part?

Tags: c#, winforms

In some images it's cropping the right parts but in other images it's displaying on the left pictureBox1 the wrong cropped part. in both pictureBoxes 1 and 2 i'm using normal SizeMode.

This screenshot show correct cropped image. On the right the rectangle i draw and this cropped part of the image in the rectangle show on the left pictureBox1 : The image size is 1024 x 640

[image: working cropped image]

in this screenshot i loaded to pictureBox2 image size 634 x 795 again drawing a rectangle with the mouse on the pictureBox2 but in pictureBox1 it's showing something else :
it looks like in this image the cropped part in pictureBox1 on the left is bigger or zommed in.

[image: the cropped image part in pictureBox1 is not the same size in the pictureBox2 drawn rectangle]

This method DRawShapes draw the rectangle on the pictureBox2 :

```
private void DrawShapes(Graphics g)
        {
            if (DrawingRects.Count == 0) return;
            g.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
            foreach (var dr in DrawingRects)
            {
                if (dr.Rect.Width > 0 && dr.Rect.Height > 0)
                {
                    using (Pen pen = new Pen(dr.DrawingcColor, dr.PenSize))
                    {
                        g.DrawRectangle(pen, dr.Rect);
                    };
                }
            }
        }
```

Using this method in pictureBox2 paint event :

```
private void pictureBox2_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (drawBorder)
            {
                ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, pictureBox2.ClientRectangle, Color.Red, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
            }

            if (pictureBox2.Image != null && selectedPath != null && DrawingRects.Count > 0)
            {
                DrawShapes(e.Graphics);
            }
        }
```

This method should make the crop and display it on the pictureBox1 :

```
public Bitmap cropAtRect(Bitmap b, Rectangle r)
        {
            Bitmap nb = new Bitmap(r.Width, r.Height);
            using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(nb))
            {
                g.DrawImage(b, -r.X, -r.Y);
                return nb;
            }
        }
```

Using this method :

```
private void pictureBox2_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Left) return;
            if (DrawingRects.Count > 0 && pictureBox2.Image != null && selectedPath != null)
            {
                if ((x >= 0 && x <= pictureBox2.Image.Size.Width) && (y >= 0 && y <= pictureBox2.Image.Size.Height))
                {
                    var dr = DrawingRects.Last();
                    if (dr.Rect.Width > 0 && dr.Rect.Height > 0)
                    {
                        rectImage = cropAtRect((Bitmap)pictureBox2.Image, dr.Rect);
                        if (saveRectangles)
                        {


                            rectangleName = GetNextName(Path.Combine(selectedPath, "Rectangle"), ".bmp"); 
                            FileList.Add($"{dr.Location}, {dr.Size}", rectangleName);
                            string json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(
        FileList,
        Formatting.Indented
    );
                            using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(Path.Combine(selectedPath, "rectangles.txt"), false))
                            {
                                sw.Write(json);
                                sw.Close();
                            }

                            rectImage.Save(rectangleName);
                            saveRectanglesCounter++;
                        }
                        pixelsCounter = rect.Width * rect.Height;

                        pictureBox1.Invalidate();
                        
                        listBox1.DataSource = FileList.Keys.ToList();
                        listBox1.SelectedIndex = listBox1.Items.Count - 1;

                        pictureBox2.Focus();
                        Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(this.pictureBox1.Image);
                        g.Clear(this.pictureBox1.BackColor);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (clearRectangles)
                    {
                        DrawingRects.Clear();
                        pictureBox2.Invalidate();
                    }

                    x = 0;
                    y = 0;
                    
                }
            }
        }
```

This line :

rectImage is a BitMap type :

```
rectImage = cropAtRect((Bitmap)pictureBox2.Image, dr.Rect);
```

and then in pictureBox1 paint event :

```
private void pictureBox1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (drawBorder)
            {
                ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, pictureBox1.ClientRectangle, Color.Red, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
            }
            if (rectImage != null && DrawingRects.Count > 0)
            {
                var dr = DrawingRects.Last();
                e.Graphics.DrawImage(rectImage, dr.Rect);

                if (clearRectangles)
                {
                    DrawingRects.Clear();
                    pictureBox2.Invalidate();
                }
            }
        }
```

The results are that when loading some image/s to the pictureBox2 and crop part of the image it's working fine but other images with different size it's not cropping it right.

Comment: **IF** the SizeMode is actually set to Normal (though, in this case, part of the images is not visible in the PictureBoxes), see the note here: [Image is not drawn at the correct spot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51456467/7444103) or here: [Position and size of combined images inside a new Bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69021795/7444103)

Comment: If the SizeMode is (or can be) different, combine with Reza Aghaei's answer here: [Translate Rectangle Position in Zoom Mode Picturebox](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53800328/7444103): it can be used to avoid other calculations, since the PictureBox Control already does this internally (and, for unspecified reasons, it doesn't *expose the numbers*)