# Bitmap image is getting scaled and is not fully visible

Tags: c#, image, image-processing, canvas, bitmap

I am working on automating the process of overlaying image into another placeholder images,Currently, I have a collection of placeholder images and for each of these placeholder images a new image is gonna get placed in top.

The issue I'm facing is that the placeholder images are getting scaled and not fully visible when overlaying the new image. I would like the placeholder images to remain unchanged, with the new image being drawn on top of each placeholder without scaling or zooming.

Here's the current code I have:

```
        // Paths to placeholder images
        string[] placeholderImagePaths =
        {
            "D:\\First-img.png",
            "D:\\Second-img.png",
            "D:\\Third-img.png"
            // Add more paths here as needed
        };

        // Get path for the new image from user input
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the path to the new image:");
        string digitalArtImagePath = Console.ReadLine();

        // Load the new image
        using (var digitalArtImage = Image.FromFile(digitalArtImagePath))
        {
            foreach (string placeholderImagePath in placeholderImagePaths)
            {
                // Load the placeholder image
                using (var placeholderImage = Image.FromFile(placeholderImagePath))
                {
                    // Create a new composite image with the dimensions of the placeholder image
                    using (var compositeImage = new Bitmap(placeholderImage.Width, placeholderImage.Height))
                    {
                        // Draw the placeholder image onto the composite image
                        using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(compositeImage))
                        {
                            graphics.DrawImage(placeholderImage, 0, 0);
                        }

                        // Resize and position the new image on the composite image
                        using (var graphics = Graphics.FromImage(compositeImage))
                        {
                            // Adjust these values to position and resize the new image
                            int digitalArtX = 100;
                            int digitalArtY = 100;
                            int digitalArtWidth = 400;
                            int digitalArtHeight = 300;

                            graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
                            graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
                            graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;

                            graphics.DrawImage(digitalArtImage, new Rectangle(digitalArtX, digitalArtY, digitalArtWidth, digitalArtHeight));
                        }

                        // Save the composite image as a JPEG
                        string compositeImagePath = Path.Combine(Path.GetDirectoryName(digitalArtImagePath), "composite_" + Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(placeholderImagePath) + ".jpg");
                        compositeImage.Save(compositeImagePath, ImageFormat.Jpeg);

                        Console.WriteLine("Composite image saved: " + compositeImagePath);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Some examples:

[image]

[image]

I can adjust the position and size of the newly image that is gonna get placed on top of placeholders but I don't know why the placeholder images are getting scaled like this.

Could someone please guide me on how to modify my code or suggest an alternative approach to achieve the desired result?

Comment: You need to provide the _destination_ rectangle rather than `Point.Empty`. Set the .`DrawImage` overloads.

Comment: See: [Image is not drawn at the correct spot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51456467/7444103) for some more information -- Also, consider the DpiAwareness of your application

Comment: @dr.null I have 2 DrawImage methods, which one do you mean? and what overload should I use?

Comment: The first one, to adjust the size of the back image. However, it seems Jimi has pointed out the right thing here. Please check out his link. Perhaps providing the 3 images to do some tests helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding these lines of code fixed the problem:

```
graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
graphics.InterpolationMode = InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
graphics.PixelOffsetMode = PixelOffsetMode.HighQuality;
```